# What can be done to improve the [eda] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process, tag-disambiguation

The tag [eda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eda) is presently linked to [Event-driven_architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_architecture) but is also known as  [Exploratory data analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploratory_data_analysis). People use the second meaning when they tag their posts, too. Examples:

1. [How can I change the caption for the Heatmap as the method takes no arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68889902/how-can-i-change-the-caption-for-the-heatmap-as-the-method-takes-no-arguments)
2. [invalid start byte error when showing datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68788601/invalid-start-byte-error-when-showing-datasets)

Would it be possible to create another tag like [eda-exploratory-data-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eda-exploratory-data-analysis) or [eda-data-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eda-data-analysis) that can be used for the second meaning exclusively?

Comment: I have nothing to add to the actual question here, the existing answer is great. But I did chuckle that before I realized this was regarding the main Stack Overflow, my first thought was neither of those, but rather [electronic design automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_design_automation). And indeed, there is a different [`eda` tag](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eda) for just that over on the Electrical Engineering StackExchange, where it belongs. Too many acronyms! :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We already have [exploratory-data-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exploratory-data-analysis).

I think all we need to do is create [event-driven-architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-driven-architecture), and retag [eda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eda) questions.