# Exploring removal of [exploratory-data-analysis]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

This is a follow-up to *[What can be done to improve the [eda] tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411154/2954547)*.

The tag [exploratory-data-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exploratory-data-analysis) is very rarely used, and when it is used, it's applied arbitrarily to questions that have better, more-relevant tags, by users who mostly don't know what they're doing.

Moreover, exploratory data analysis as a stand-alone topic probably doesn't even belong on this site. Such questions belong be on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) or [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Looks like the first/oldest question tagged with it is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67555608) (May 16 '21) which is on-topic on SO, regardless of the tag should be there or not. With my non-existence knowledge about it, it does look like a meta tag. However, looks like there is also a similar tag related to the topic: [tag:data-analysis] (3300+ questions).

Comment: @AndrewT. Maybe it should be made a synonym for (or otherwise merged with) [tag:data-analysis].

Comment: There are only [2 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bexploratory-data-analysis%5D+exploratory) tagged with this that actually have the word exploratory in them. The tag only has 23 questions in total (some already bound to be Roomba'd) so I think it is possible to simply retag all questions with `data-analysis` and see if it even gets created again... Otherwise, just make it a synonym. I doubt it adds a lot of value over `data-analysis`

Comment: @AndrewT. as someone that sometimes have tasks of data analysis, the things that you need to know are all off topic.